# Disambiguation between Tool (the band) and tool (for music work or appreciation)

Tags: discussion, tags

The [tool](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool) tag is not clear to me. As it doesn't have nor usage guidance nor wiki.

At this time, it has been used 4 times, twice for the band Tool, twice for musicians or listeners tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool should only be used to talk about the band Tool. Using tools as a tag to talk about gear, software, items, ect makes no sense as grouping unrelated items together just because the can be classified as a "tool". The resulting group of questions will just be an odd bunch of questions that aren't really related.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

- [tool](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool) for the band.

  > Usage guidance:
  >   For questions about the American band Tool formed in California in 1990. Current members are Maynard James Keenan (vocal), Adam Jones (guitar), Danny Carey (drums), and Justin Chancellor (bass guitar). Don't use this tag for tools used by musicians or listeners, use [tools](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) instead.
- [tools](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) for musicians or listeners tools.

  > Usage guidance:
  >   For questions about tools used by musicians or listeners. Don't use this tag for questions about the band Tool, use [tool](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool) instead.

Comment: Why do we need a tools tag? In what context does that make sense? Just because it is used that way  _does not mean_ that is a good tag or a needed tag.